# Azure PaaS Compatibility Check

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a client willing to move to Azure PaaS with their ASP.NET web service layer. We are likely to move as Azure Web App with some jobs as Web Jobs. Is there any tool that I can run to check whether the code is compatible with PaaS Web App?

I heard a tool called xRay but not able to find it out. Would love to get your suggestions on this?
What about SQL Server On Prem to Azure SQL - is there any similar tool to check compatibility?

Comment: The SQL Azure Migration Wizard is pretty good for the sql checks

Comment: Usually your app will be compatible with Azure. You will need to add webroles for Web project with some cloud settings. For  database I think above comment should be useful. If for some reason code is accessing file system will cause trouble in paas model. We don't get non volatile disk in paas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Azure App Service Migration Assistant**

The Azure App Service Migration site and the tool can be utilized to migrate sites from Windows and Linux web servers to Azure App Service. As part of the migration the tool will create Web Apps and databases on Azure if needs be, publish content and publish your database.

**SQL Database Migration Wizard**

The SQL Database Migration Wizard can be used to migrate an on-premises SQL Server database to the latest Azure SQL Database Update (V12).

**References:**

[Azure App Service Migration Assistant](https://www.movemetothecloud.net/)

[Azure App Service Migration Assistant Compatibility Analysis](https://www.movemetothecloud.net/Resources)

[Migrate an enterprise web app to Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-migration-from-iis-server/)

[SQL Database Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/)

[Fix SQL Server database compatibility issues using SQL Azure Migration Wizard before migration to Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate-fix-compatibility-issues/)